# Incompatible library version RSiena

Tags: r, macos

I'm trying to load the RSiena package into R, but keep getting this error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RSiena’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libtk8.6.dylib requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libfontconfig.1.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

I tried installing three ways: 
`install.packages("RSiena")`  , `install.packages("RSiena", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` , and installing straight from tgz file (from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSiena/index.html).

The first two installation methods do not give any error and say `The downloaded binary packages are in /var/folders/mk/__r_sbzn5mx88x04mrlycsg00000gq/T//RtmpbxlMY8/downloaded_packages`.The third option gives this message `Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'`

None allow me to load the package. I'm working with R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) in RStudio Version 1.1.423 on Mac OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.6).

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: It looks like the problem is related to tcltk and it's libraries, not Rsiena. Have you tried reinstalling tcltk?

Comment: @C. Braun I tried to reinstall tcltk and got this: '> install.packages("tcltk")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is a base package, and should not be updated' **Maybe I need to switch to an earlier version of R?**

When I tried library(tcltk) I received the same error message  'Reason: Incompatible library version: libtk8.6.dylib requires version 11.0.0 or later, but libfontconfig.1.dylib provides version 10.0.0'

Comment: The issue is with `libfontconfig.1.dylib`, What is the output of this command `locate libfontconfig.dylib | grep -E '/usr/local|opt'`? If others show up in the `locate` command try doing `otool -L libfontconfig.dylib` on them and see what they versions are... It appears you might have MacPorts installed in which case you should be able to do `sudo port selfupdate` followed by `sudo port upgrade outdated`.

Comment: @l'L'l To the first suggestion: locate libfontconfig.dylib | grep -E '/usr/local|opt'

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:
  
  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.

Comment: If you do indeed have MacPorts installed try updating, otherwise run the suggested command `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`, then what I mentioned before.

Comment: SOLUTION. I installed XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org and now the package loads successfully. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION. I installed XQuartz from xquartz.macosforge.org and now the package loads successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version (RSiena v.1.2.26) of [rsiena](/questions/tagged/rsiena) addresses `tcltk` issues, and is now available on Github here: https://github.com/snlab-nl/rsiena.